# Unity C# Instantiate prefab not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im having trouble with referencing a object in play not a prefab  Ver simple code that will blow up a car when the player hits hit.  The sphere collider gets turned on to do damage when it blows up

So what happens is when there are 2 or more cars in the playfield, If the player hits one of them , the first one put into play will blow up then any further attempt to hit them hill lock up as the gameobject does not exist anymore.  I know the problem is referencing the object in play not the prefab but how do i do that

2 codes on the object that blows up

```
public class ObjectExplode : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This goes on objects that will be destroyed that hurt tags.
    [SerializeField] AudioSource explosionSound;
        [SerializeField] GameObject explosionPrefab;// Set the explosion particle 
    [HideInInspector] public bool explode = false;// make the object explode

    private SphereCollider sphereCollider;

    void Start()
    {
        sphereCollider = GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
        sphereCollider.enabled = false;
    }

    public void Explode()
    {
        sphereCollider.enabled = true;
        GameObject explosionClone = (GameObject)Instantiate
            (explosionPrefab, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);//as GameObject;
        Destroy(gameObject, 2);
        explosionSound.Play();
    }

}
```

Here is the second script

```
public class ObjectDamage : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] int startingHealth = 1000;// starting health of the car
    private int currentHealth;// current health of car
    //Class and componant assigns
    private ObjectExplode objectExplode;


    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = startingHealth;// start  the level with ful health

        //Class and componant setups
        objectExplode = FindObjectOfType<ObjectExplode>();
    }

    void Death()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);// destroy the car 
    }

    public void Hurt(int damageToTake)
    {
        currentHealth -= damageToTake;
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Death();
            objectExplode.Explode();
        }
    }
}
```

Corrected code for those interested

```
public class ObjectDamage : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] int startingHealth = 1000;// starting health of the object
    private int currentHealth;// current health of object
    private ObjectExplode objectExplode;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = startingHealth;// start  the level with ful health
        objectExplode = gameObject.GetComponent<ObjectExplode>();

    }

    void Death()
    {
       gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void Hurt(int damageToTake)
    {
        currentHealth -= damageToTake;
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Death();
           objectExplode.Explode();
        }
    }
}
```

And second code

```
public class ObjectExplode : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This goes on objects that will be destroyed 
    [SerializeField] AudioSource explosionSound;
    [SerializeField] GameObject explosionPrefab;// Set the explosion particle 
    [HideInInspector] public bool explode = false;// make the object explode

    private SphereCollider sphereCollider;

    void Start()
    {
        sphereCollider = GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
        sphereCollider.enabled = false;
    }

    public void Explode()
    {
        sphereCollider.enabled = true;
        GameObject explosionClone = Instantiate(explosionPrefab, gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().transform.position,gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().transform.rotation);
        Destroy(explosionClone, 2);
        explosionSound.Play();
    }
}
```

And add this code to the character you want to do the damage

```
public class DamageToGive : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int damage = 0;
    public int damageToGive;
    public string getTag = "";
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == getTag && damage == 0)
        {    
            if (getTag == "TAGGOESHERE")
            {
                other.GetComponent<ZombieHealth>().Hurt(damageToGive);
            }
            damage++;
        }
    }
    Void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(damage > 0)
        { 
            damage = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added fixed code for Reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course it's going to blow up the first one you placed into the scene.  That's what [`FindObjectOfType()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) *does.* It finds the **first** object in the scene hierarchy that has the type specified.

> **Description:**
>
> Returns the first active loaded object of Type type.

You want to blow up a *specific* car you need to get a reference to *that specific car.*

It looks like your second script is attached to the same object that the first script is attached to, so what you actually are looking for is [`gameObject.GetComponent<ObjectExplode>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html).

Comment: I was able to use GetComponent to fix the issue with the cars.  What was happening was not even in these codes.  It was in my damage code.  I was calling FindObjectOfType  just didnt notice it wasnt working right